# ORM modelling - entity type vs. value type

Tags: mysql, orm, entity, object-role-modeling

I am new to ORM modelling and have a simple question.

Let's say I want a list of movies, their names, release dates and genres. A movie is here represented by the value type "name". But should I use "release date" and "genre" as entity types or a value types? I've seen different ORM models using different approaches. What is the reason for choosing one over the other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Movie titles get re-used in a movie remake. Arguably never in the same year however, so the title and the production year (or release year? ensure you specify that!) should be enough to uniquely identify a particular movie production. Personally, I liked "The Italian Job (1969)" not the 2003 remake, which was positively awful.

The title is just a value - a piece of text. A Year on the other hand, that's an entity type, which is identified by a year number. You can verify this by asking a Muslim or the Chinese what year it is - they both have their own epoch which are not based on Common Era. Different numbers, same year. So the number isn't the same thing as the year.

It gets worse: their years don't roll over at December 31 either, but lets ignore that for now. Also, an astronomical (sidereal) year has 366.25 days, not 365.25, because that's the rate at which we circle the sky. One extra rotation "unwinds" one orbit around the sun. So it's really important to be clear on what your values mean.

Using this logic, a Date is an entity type, not a value type. It just happens that our databases have "value" support for Dates, which is why they also provide functions to tear them apart, etc. But a Date is an entity type, not a value type. You might decide to ignore this if your tooling makes it too inconvenient however.

Likewise for Genre. Different people might have different names for the same genre; a genre is not necessarily uniquely identified by its name. So you have the entity type Genre, identified by a value type GenreName. You're asserting that for your purposes, each Genre has exactly (and only) one name; but the use of an entity recognises the possibility of a different identifier being preferred. A Genre is not the same thing as the Genre Name.

I hope that gives you a clear rationale.

Comment: I think this question is better answered by looking at the purpose of the model and the domain you are modeling. In many cases, I would say it's perfectly appropriate to model year as a value type, such as when stating when a movie has been made, because in this case you're just interested in the Gregorian year value. Using entities clutters the model here.

Anything can be modeled as entities: Asking a French person about a movie title would also give you a different answer than asking an American since titles get translated, and if you want to model this, you should also use entity types.

Comment: Mathias, are you familiar with ORM? "Using entities clutters the model" is true in an ER diagram, but not in an Object Role Model (ORM) diagram. You get the same number of boxes either way - a dashed box containing Year, or a solid box containing Year(.Nr). The latter is more explicit.

Comment: To me it's conceptually simpler. In this case you leave me wondering: Does using the entity Year(.nr) have an advantage over YearNr? Why is the value PhoneNr preferred over the entity Phone(.nr), while Car(.regNr) is preferred over CarRegNr (these are modeled as such in [Halpin's Information Modeling and Relational Databases p. 486](https://goo.gl/aoB2sp))? Does this not simply depend on the purpose and domain of the model? Wouldn't a model of a phone company's subscriptions require an entity Phone(.nr), or an international film database require an entity Name?

Comment: A phone (mobile) is identified by its IMEI, not by the number(s) it may answer to from time to time. A car is identified by VIN, and a RegNr has narrower applicability (the same car may later use a new RegNr). But all these are secondary to the main issue: a Value Type has values that can be *written*. I cannot write a Year, but I can write a YearNr. So a Year is not a value type, and a YearNr is. I cannot write a Person, but I can write their Name. A very simple criterion, really. This is also the way Dr Halpin (with whom I have regular discussions) models it.